# Obtaining sensors data while the screen is off (Android 4.0+)

Tags: android, android-sensors, screen-off

As far as I know on Android devices there is no 100%-sure way to get the data from device sensors while the screen is off. There are some workarounds, but they do not work always. But all the posts I read were describing Android versions ~2.2.

Does anyone know whether the bug was fixed in Android 4.0+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) `WakeLock` works like charm.