# Android sensor logging suspended

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I have an app that logs acceleration, rotation and gps data. The data is written to a log file on the sd card.
When i plot the data on pc i see that the logging of acceleration and rotation data is suspended randomly for 10-100 seconds. The gps data is nearly equidistant.

It's implemented as one background service that listens to sensor-events and location-events. I know that there is a bug with getting sensor data when screen is off. But I'm using a Nexus 5 where it should work.

At the green line (acceleration) you see the problem. Sometimes it's suspended.

> [image]

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: no ideas?
I would be happy if someone can tell me, what I can try.

Comment: I found this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612065/obtaining-sensors-data-while-the-screen-is-off-android-4-0/23616068#23616068)

So i tried to do this in onStartCommand(..):
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "logging service lock");
wakeLock.acquire();

And this in onDestroy:
wakeLock.release();

But it did not help.
Any ideas?

Comment: How to get timestamps of sensors for yourself or from android API?